# Illumination issue drawing triangles

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d, glut

I'm drawing the faces of a cube using two triangles. But I'm not getting quite the result that I expected.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ull0s.png]

The image below shows the two triangles with coordinates:

```
(1, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1)
```

and

```
(0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1)
```

respectively. I can't figure out where the problem is since both are specified in CCW order and with the same normal vector `(0, 0, 1)`. The light source is in the same position as the eye.

What do you think the problem is due to?

**EDIT:** Just solved it by specifying only one normal vector for each polygon instead of specifying one for each vertex for each polygon.

Comment: Can you put the code where you draw the triangles and set their normals? It doesn't look at all like all normals are `(0, 0, 1)`.

Comment: Another reason to use `GL_QUADS`

Comment: @paddy `QL_QUADS` were deprecated in 3.0 and removed in 3.1, so might as well get used to triangles and triangle strips.